# Create json query string in python from a list of json name

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a JSON object like this:

```py
a = {'s1':12134,'s2':{'s3':678,'s4':'blah','s5':'sample'}}
```

and list of its keys:

```py
l = ['s2','s3']
```

How do I query `s3` value dynamically using the list `l`? Basically using the list I want to create Python code as follows:

```
a[l[0]][l[2]]
```

which will return the value `678`. How can create the above statement using the list `l`?

Answer (score 0):

For getting several dictionary values, these methods will work. I will call your `l1`, `keys` and `a`, `values` for the sake of this explanation.

Output as a list:

```
output = []
values = {'s1':12134,'s2':{'s3':678,'s4':'blah','s5':'sample'}}
keys = ['s1','s2','s3','s4','s5']
for key in keys:
    output.append(values[key])
```

Output as a dictionary:

```
output = {}
values = {'s1':12134,'s2':{'s3':678,'s4':'blah','s5':'sample'}}
keys = ['s1','s2','s3','s4','s5']
for key in keys:
    output[key] = values[key]
```

Comment: Sorry my bad. Formulated the question in the wrong way.  Updated the question.  Want to query a['s2']['s3']. I cant do this directly as list values and the json content will change.  Any way of doing it??

Comment: All good. You can literally just call a['s2']['s3'] and save it as a new variable. If you are worried about in-place modification, you can just use `a['s2']['s3'].copy()`. Thanks, Larry